# Use regex to seperate 3 variables

Tags: c#, regex

If I have a string in this format:

```
string placeholder = "[[Ford:Focus(blue)]]";
```

or

```
string placeholder = "[[Ford:Focus(light blue)]]";
```

What regex could I use to populate the three variables below?

```
string make = ?
string model = ?
string colour = ?
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `([^:\[\]]*):([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)` https://regex101.com/r/1J048G/2

Comment: Can this placeholder be in a longer string?

Comment: Try this ([\w\d]+):([\w\d]+)\(+([\w\d\s]+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid RegEx - another approach with `Split()`

```
string placeholder = "[[Ford:Focus(light blue)]]";
string[] result = placeholder.Split(new[] { '[', ']', '(', ')', ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string make = result[0];
string model = result[1];
string colour = result[2];
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0iKNgJ

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Regex and Groups:

```
string strRegex = @"\[(?<make>\w*):(?<model>\w*)\((?<colour>.*)\)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"[[Ford:Focus(blue)]]";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
    if (myMatch.Success)
    {
        var make = myMatch.Groups["make"].Value;
        var model = myMatch.Groups["model"].Value;
        var colour = myMatch.Groups["colour"].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can `Success` ever be `false` when the `Match` is returned by `Matches`?

Comment: You are right.. I guess you do not need to test if the match is successfull. I must admit, I just copied the code from [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) they seem to to think that checking for Success is a good idea..

Comment: Oh well, better safe than sorry - additional checks never hurt.

Comment: If colour is optional (so it could be just [[Ford:Focus]] it won't match..is there an amendment that can be made to allow that?

Comment: @thegunner: you can make the braket optional with this regex: `string strRegex = @"\[(?<make>\w*):(?<model>\w*)\(?(?<colour>.*)\)";` then it should also match the string without colour..

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
([^:\[\]]*):([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/1J048G/3)

Explanation:

- `([^:\[\]]*)` captures make (anything that is not a square bracket nor `:`)
- `:` separates model
- `([^(]*)` matches model
- `\(([^)]*)\)` matches colour (everything but closing bracket) inside brackets

Comment: not sure what you mean? Please, see the demo

Comment: @mrzasa The first capture group contains the `[[` and anything else that comes before `Ford`.

Comment: Forgot to update the link to demo, please see now :).

Answer (score 0):

If the brackets are part of the string, you could use something like this

```
\[\[(.*):(.*)\((.*)\)
```